# ¿Como registrar datos de un formulario en phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

apenas estoy empezando con esto de las bases de datos, y necesito crear un formulario de registro en el que es ponen los datos del nombre, apellido paterno, apellido materno, telefono y correo electronico.

La cosa es que ya tengo mi formulario hecho y tambien ya esta conectado en phpMyAdmin y estoy ocupando Xammp, el problema es que cuando intento guardar mis datos, no aparecen en mi base de datos. Y no se en que estoy mal, ya estuve intentando varias cosas pero ninguna funciona.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
<?php
$servidor="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$clave="";
$baseDeDatos="bd_anca";

$enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);

if(!$enlace){
echo"Error en la conexion con el servidor";
}  
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_contacto.css"> 
     <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form_reg" action="">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="input" placeholder="Nombre"
        required autofocus>
        <input type="text" name="apellidop" class="input" placeholder="Apellido Paterno"
        required>
        <input type="text" name="apellidom" class="input" placeholder="Apellido Materno"
        required>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="text" name="telefono" class="input" placeholder="Telefono" 
        required>
        <textarea class="input" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Escriba aqui su mensaje"></textarea>

        <div class="btn_form">
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn_submit" value="Enviar">
        </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
  </html>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellidop = $_POST["apellidop"];
    $apellidom = $_POST["apellidom"];
    $correo = $_POST["email"];
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    /*Id*/

    $insertarDatos = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(
                                                '$apellidop', 
                                                '$apellidom',
                                                '$nombre',
                                                '$telefono',
                                                '$correo')";

    $ejecutarInsertar = mysqli_query($enlace, $insertarDatos);

    if(!$ejecutarInsertar){
        echo"Error en la linea de sql";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: intenta poniendo el método a tu `form`  `<form method="POST"`

Comment: Si, era eso. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. :D

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto cuando creas un formulario el "**method**" es `GET`, por lo tanto al preguntar si esta seteada la variable `$_POST['enviar']` siempre sera falso. 
Intenta definiendo el **method** en tu formulario para que sea de tipo POST

```
<form class="form_reg" action="" method="post">
```

Si queres mas infor sobre los formularios podes encontrar aca [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: Te agradezco por ayudarme, si era eso.